# html.Parse function returns nil instead of parsed html

Tags: html, go, dom

I started to learn Go and I try to run this program but *html.Parse* from **golang.org/x/net/html** returns nil when I try to get parsed HTML. I try different things but I can't find out what's going on, so I appreciate it if someone explains what happens under the hood, thanks.

```Go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func main() {
    doc, err := html.Parse(os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "findlinks1: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(doc)
    for _, link := range visit(nil, doc) {
        fmt.Printf("link is %v", link)
        fmt.Println(link)
    }

func visit(links []string, n *html.Node) []string {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                links = append(links, a.Val)
            }
        }
    }
    if c := n.FirstChild; c != nil {
        c = c.NextSibling
        links = visit(links, c)
    }
    return links
}
```

I'm using go version 1.13.8 and my operating system is Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.
When I print doc I get this message:

```sh
&{<nil> 0xc0000ca070 0xc0000ca0e0 <nil> <nil> 2    []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parsed document isn't `nil`, else you'd only see printed `nil` and not something like `&{...}`.

Visiting all children is a loop, yet you only check if the `n` node has a first child, and if it does, you don't even use it but traverse the next sibling. This makes no sense.

To visit all children, use a loop like this:

```
for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
    links = visit(links, c)
}
```

Testing it:

```
s := `<a href="http://first.com">first</a><b><a href="http://second.com">second</a></b>`
doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "findlinks1: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
fmt.Println(doc)
for _, link := range visit(doc) {
    fmt.Println("link is", link)
}
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/SNwHLZJRhGP)):

```
&{<nil> 0xc00012e070 0xc00012e070 <nil> <nil> 2    []}
link is http://first.com
link is http://second.com
```

Comment: My mistake was using if instead of for which is make no sense. thank you for your response.